# Error Apache CXF 3.3.7 with WildFly 17.0.1 : IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred

Tags: java, wsdl, wildfly, cxf

I am using CFX 3.3.7 With JDK 13 and wildfly 17.0.1 final.
But wsdl Not created, This is the error.

```
IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.



java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.getLaunchConfigurationName(ClasspathShortener.java:377)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.createClassPathArgumentFile(ClasspathShortener.java:384)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.shortenClasspathUsingClasspathArgumentFile(ClasspathShortener.java:298)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.shortenClasspathIfNecessary(ClasspathShortener.java:220)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.ClasspathShortener.shortenCommandLineIfNecessary(ClasspathShortener.java:161)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMRunner.getCommandLine(StandardVMRunner.java:471)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMRunner.run(StandardVMRunner.java:492)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.LaunchUtils.launch(LaunchUtils.java:113)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.creation.core.commands.Java2WSCommand.execute(Java2WSCommand.java:96)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:421)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:361)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:214)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:296)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1034)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:266)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:93)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(SimpleWizardPage.java:138)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:911)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:468)
      at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
      at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4175)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3988)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3587)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(DynamicPopupWizard.java:132)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:239)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4175)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3988)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3587)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:660)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```